# Auto-update apps by APKPure

Tags: apkpure

Is there a way to auto-update apps by APKPure, similar to what the Google Play Store offers?

Apps that are installed through APKPure require constant manual update-management.

Comment: For any app to be updated silently (that is, without user intervention)  by another app, the latter/installer app needs to have INSTALL_PACKAGES permission granted. That's not gonna happen unless the app is a system app. Or, if you have root access than that's the other way.

Comment: Is that a general statement or specific to APKPure? I have root access, but the app never prompted me for the INSTALL_PACKAGES permission?

Comment: It is a general statement. Root access is useful if the app makes use of it. Your Apkpure app might not have been designed to make use of it.